# iOS like navigation drawer in android

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to create ios like navigation drawer in android using xamarin

1. Master and Detail page should slide from left to right and should not overlap detail page
2. Master page should occupy full height (either after notification bar or including notificationbar)

Comment: Is the built-in Android navigation drawer not appropriate for your application?  See https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html for an example and http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html for a tutorial to create one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i have gmail like navigation drawer (master page) in xamarin.forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908670/can-i-have-gmail-like-navigation-drawer-master-page-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Yes but both the questions were asked by me and still searching for solution