# Difficulty while writing custom renderer for navigation drawer(MasterDetailPage) xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, navigation-drawer, master-detail, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms mvvm light architecture and targeting Android & iOS.
I am currently writing custom renderer for navigation drawer(MasterDetailPage).
I am currently writing custom renderer for Android and i have tried many things.
Currently my MasterDetail Page renders according to OS's default behaviour i.e. in Android master page starts below the app bar but i wanted my master page to popover app bar or start above the app bar like gmail,stack exchange android app etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i have gmail like navigation drawer (master page) in xamarin.forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908670/can-i-have-gmail-like-navigation-drawer-master-page-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I can't find solution for that question as well

Answer (score 0):

use this theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar for the expected behaviour

Comment: But i want actionbar as well

Answer (score 0):

There exists one already, as of this writing it is out of date though (not targeting Xamarin Forms 2): https://github.com/nativecode-dev/oss-xamarin. Perhaps you can use that?